# Multi-Threading in PyQt 5

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, python-multithreading

I've been learning about multi-threading, specifically in the context of a PyQt 5 application.

Initially I implemented a version using 'threading', but have since learnt that I should be using 'QThread' to allow use of signals / slots, e.g:

> workerThread = QThread()
>   workerObject = Worker(cmdlist)
>   workerObject.moveToThread(workerThread)
>   workerThread.started.connect(workerObject.run)
>   workerObject.finished.connect(workerThread.quit)

However, is it possible to design a system in which:

- Each class is associated with a thread created at run-time.
- The'main' component of the program can then call functions within those
  classes, which are executed within the separate thread for the given
  class.

An example of the behaviour would be this:

> ```
> thread = threading.Thread(target=self.run, args=())
> ```

But how would I implement similar behaviour with QThread?
Or my understanding of threads in Python in-correct?

Comment: I believe the link in my answer explain in detail how to get promote functions to threads. However, It is not a good idea to associate threads for each class. That is bad design. Only put your long running tasks in threads. The more explicit the threads the better.

Answer (score 3):

[Martin Fitzpatrick](https://www.mfitzp.com/) has an amazing guide on how to do this using QThreadPools. I think this is what you're looking for.

[Multithreading PyQt applications with QThreadPool](https://www.pythonguis.com/tutorials/multithreading-pyqt-applications-qthreadpool/)

Comment: learnpyqt.com doesn't seem to exist anymore, which all of Martin's posts seem to link back to.

Comment: @MarkCarpenterJr Updated the links!

Comment: Thank you! For some reason my region's ISP blocks the server that martin uses as a host. So odd, even when using Google or Cloudflare DNS. No worries though I have a proxy in place to work around these cases.

Comment: That guide is great !